# Broadcast Using This Tool (BUTT) Install Issues

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I've successfully installed Broadcast Using This Tool (BUTT) and Icecast2 on Windows, and I can stream audio.  However, I'm unable to install Broadcast Using This Tool (BUTT) on Linux.  I've tried to install BUTT on Linux Mint version 17, Linux Fedora version 21, and Linux Ubuntu version 14.  I used these commands to install these dependencies in Linux:

- sudo apt-get install gcc
- sudo apt-get install gcc-c++
- sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev
- sudo apt-get install libportaudio-dev
- sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev
- sudo apt-get install libfltk1.3-dev
- sudo apt-get install libmp3lame-dev
- sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss
- sudo apt-get install jackd2

If I install BUTT using **sudo apt-get install butt**, when I enter "butt" into Terminal, I get this output.

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib setup.c:548:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib setup.c:548:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib setup.c:548:(add_elem) Cannot obtain info for CTL elem (MIXER,'IEC958 Playback Default',0,0,0): No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
```

If I download any of the BUTT .deb files from sourceforge, and install BUTT from the .deb, I get the same output when entering "butt" into Terminal.

Lastly, I tried to install BUTT from the source .tar.gz.  I'm able to run these commands in Terminal.

- cd /home
- cd jeremy
- cd Downloads
- tar -xzf butt-0.1.13.tar.gz
- cd butt-0.1.13
- ./configure

Next, when I enter **make** into Terminal, I get this output.

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jeremy/Downloads/butt-0.1.13'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/jeremy/Downloads/butt-0.1.13/src'
depbase=`echo butt.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
    g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -IFLTK   -g -O2  -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include

/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12    -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -MT butt.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o butt.o butt.cpp &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
In file included from cfg.h:19:0,

                 from butt.cpp:37:
port_audio.h:61:24: error: ‘PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo’ does not name a type
                  const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                        ^
port_audio.h:61:50: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘timeInfo’ with no type [-fpermissive]
                  const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                                                  ^
port_audio.h:62:18: error: ‘PaStreamCallbackFlags’ has not been declared
                  PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                  ^
make[2]: *** [butt.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jeremy/Downloads/butt-0.1.13/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jeremy/Downloads/butt-0.1.13'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I am late but hopefully it will help someone to install BUTT on ubuntu 16.04 (my case). Sorry If I am out of topic.

## Dependencies:

apt-get install libfltk1.3-dev

apt-get install libportaudio-dev

apt-get install libvorbis-dev

apt-get install libogg-dev

apt-get install libopus-dev

apt-get install libflac-dev

apt-get install libsamplerate-dev

apt-get install libmp3lame-dev

apt-get install build-essentials

apt-get install gcc

apt-get install gcc-c++

apt-get install portaudio19-dev

apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss

apt-get install jackd2

## If you encounter any problem regarding portaudio

Go to: http://www.portaudio.com/download.html and download (in my case) pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz

extract the file and do:

tar -xzf pa_stable__date.tgz

cd portaudio

./configure

make

make install

## If you encounter any problem regarding the lbfdk_aac

apt-get install libfdk-aac-dev

## Installing BUTT:

tar -xzf butt-.tar.gz #your butt version in my case: tar -xzf

butt-0.1.16.tar.gz

cd butt-0.1.13

./configure

make

sudo make install

Comment: This is a helpful answer, as you have shared additional packages that can be installed to ensure butt is able to startup and function properly. Hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

After making this post, I continued to try to resolve this issue, but I was unable to get BUTT to detect audio in Linux.  I think this might have something to do with the dependencies in Linux, such as portaudio or jack, but I've not yet found the culprit.  As a temporary solution, I'm running BUTT on Windows, so it might just be recommended to go with Windows for the BUTT software.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but I've been using BUTT since Fedora 20, and now have it installed on Fedora 24.  The same steps works for all versions of Fedora 20+ :

1. Install the Broadcast Using This Tool (Butt) repository.
   Create a file named /etc/yum.repos.d/butt.repo and include the following lines:

   [fedora-butt]

   name=broadcast using this tool

   baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/comzeradd/butt/fedora-20/x86_64/

   enabled=1

   skip_if_unavailable=1

   gpgcheck=0

   [fedora-butt-source]

   name=broadcast using this tool - Source

   baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/comzeradd/butt/fedora-20/SRPMS

   enabled=0

   skip_if_unavailable=1

   gpgcheck=0
2. Install the butt application:

   dnf install butt

   or

   yum install butt
3. Good luck